# Morera's Theorem and independence of path

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine whether 
$$
G(z)=\int_{1}^{z}\frac{1}{t} dt
$$
is independent of the path joining $1$ and $z$ , and discuss the relationship of your answer to Morera's Theorem .....  I believe that as long as the paths goes through a region that excludes the origin ,the integral is independent of the path.... but I am not sure if this is correct or what type of argument is required here , in particular the relation of the answer to Morera's theorem is not clear to me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about traversing the unit circle for $z=1$?
$$
\int_C\frac 1zdz=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{e^{it}}(ie^{it})dt=\int_0^{2\pi}idt=2\pi i
$$

Comment: Yes , but I do not understand how this solves the problem , in particular the relationship to Morera ...and so is it independent of path...please explain more...

Comment: Hint: there is a trivial path from $1$ to itself, such that $\int_1^1\frac 1tdt=0\neq 2\pi i$. What does this tell you about path independence?

Comment: It tells me that it is NOT independent of PATH????

Comment: Yes, because the loop surrounds a pole at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

some thoughts may be of assistance:

suppose we have a circuit $\partial \Gamma$ which encloses a simply-connected open region $\Gamma$ which excludes the origin.

on $\Gamma \cup  \partial \Gamma$ we  have:
$$
\frac{dz}{z} = \frac{(x-iy)(dx+idy)}{x^2+y^2} =\frac{(xdx+ydy)+i(xdy-ydx)}{x^2+y^2}
$$
dealing with the real and imaginary parts by turn, Green's theorem shows that the integral around $\partial \Gamma$ is zero.

set $L=\frac{x-iy}{r^2}$,  and $M=\frac{y+ix}{r^2}$
then
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = -\frac{i}{r^2}-\frac{2(x-iy)y}{r^4}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial M}{\partial x} = \frac{i}{r^2}-\frac{2(y+ix)x}{r^4}
$$
thus
$$
\int_{\partial \Gamma} \frac{dz}{z} = \int_{\partial \Gamma}Ldx+Mdy=\int_{\Gamma} (\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}) dx dy \\
$$
but, as is easily checked,
$$
\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 0
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer ...so since if we (in the other case) compute this integral and get 2(pi) i (I mean the case were the region includes the origin ) this implies that the integral is NOT independent of path???

Comment: the implication is not quite so strong as that. if the origin lies in $\Gamma$ the argument fails because the integrand has a singularity. however the result shown here allows you to evaluate such an integral round an arbitrarily small circle centered at $O$